# Jetty / Jackson handling empty requests as DTOs implicitly?

Tags: java, jackson, jetty

I have reached a point in my development life where I don't want to have defensive null checks on all my controllers.

e.g.

```
public FooResponseDto getFoo(FooRequestDto request) throws ServiceException {
        if (request == null) {
            throw new ServiceException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST,
                    ErrorCode.FOO_REQUEST_EMPTY, "Reward Request was empty", "Foobar");
        }
        ....
```

Is there a way I can make Jackson or Jetty detect that a client has sent an empty request to an endpoint. Rather than me having to explicitly check that the DTO initialised from that request is not empty?

Thanks